# Surds operations in Excel spreadsheet.

Tags: calculus

I would like to know whether Surds operations work in Excel spreadsheets?

Example :

Cell E1= 2√3

Cell E2= 4√3

Will Cell E3=Sum(E1,E2) = 6√3?

And other Surds operations viz product, division etc?

Will the Data type for inputing Surds values in Cells should be Decimal numbers?

Thanks & Regards,

Prashant S Akerkar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surds work as you hoped except that they will be translated into base-$10$ approximations in each visible cell. The precision, however, is great enough that, most of the time, the results are the same as if symbolic manipulation were used.

For example
$$
E1:"=2*SQRT(3)"\space \Rightarrow3.46410161513775\\
E2:"=3*SQRT(3)"\space\Rightarrow 5.19615242270663\\
E3:"=SUM(E1,E2)"    \Rightarrow 8.66025403784439\\
E4:\space"=E1*E2" \Rightarrow 18
$$

If you go to the menu : Format.Cells, you can select "number" and there will be anything from integers, scientific notation, to currency to decimals up to 15 digits or more as well as fractions e.g. $2/5$ up to 3 digits long for numerator and denominator. There is no format to show surds but, as I said, the precision is so great that you can go to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5Csqrt%7B3%7D*3%5Csqrt%7B5%7D) if you need more.